# how to calculate as many primes as we can in ten seconds using threads in java

Tags: java, java-threads

I just started java and I am trying to learn java as much as possible. I was trying to solve a problem but couldn't get the right solution. I have tried this program according to my own logic, ended in failure. Looking forwards for someone's guidence.

```
 public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable
 {
    Thread t;
    ThreadDemo()
        {
        t=new Thread(this,"Child");
        t.start();  
        }
    public void run()
        {
        try 
         {
          Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
        }
    public static void main(String[] args)
     {
        ThreadDemo td=new ThreadDemo();
        Thread t1=Thread.currentThread();
        t1.setName("prime");
          try 
        {
        for(int i=0;;i++)
            {
                 if(i!=0&&i!=1&& i%i ==1 && i%2!=0)
                 {
                     Thread.sleep(1);
                     System.out.println(i + "j");
                 }
             }  
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}
     }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to use a thread, because you want to learn how to use them? Or do think that you need a thread for this?

Comment: @Sheldon I am trying to go with threads . To some extent I understand threads and how they works theoretically . But in-case of practical (in java) I can't get the hang of it.

Comment: In that case i suggest that you start with a non-threaded prime-test function. If that works, you can wrap a thread around it.